# CSV importing but not reading in anything but first column

Tags: matlab, csv

I am trying to plot data from the Sensor Data application of my Ipod Touch (it lets you capture accelerometer, gyro, and other sensors data). The way it stores this data is a CSV where the first row is headers for the variable names and then the following rows are data.

I understand that matlabs csvread() function does not allow mixed type csv files so when i imported i attepted to import everything except the first row by typing

```
M = csvread(testfile, 1, 0)
```

under the impression that this will import all columns and all rows except the first row.

But when i try to print a part of the matrix with

```
M(1:5,1:5)
```

displays zeros in every row and column except for the first column which displays the first row-first columns value over and over again. I tried changing this to M(1:10,1:10) and M(1:60,1:42) (there are only 42 total columns in the CSV) it doesnt change anything. The entire CSV is 2196 rows (including the header row).

I am a beginner in matlab but from the documentation i read I dont see why this would not work. Can i get some help importing and plotting CSV data? thanks!

REMOVED SENSOR DATA BECAUSE OF LOCATION

Comment: Can you get this to work with a simple file you make yourself? Are there any "strange" characters in the file? Are you sure the data is comma separated (and not just blanks)? Show us a couple of lines of the file you are attempting to import - copy/paste.

Comment: I will add to the end of my post some lines of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will seem like a non-answer...

When I copy these lines and save them to a file (`sensor.csv`), then do `M = csvread('sensor.csv', 1, 0);` (just as you did), Matlab creates a "sensible" array for M with dimensions [30 42].

Now when I try to print it out, it seems to have a value in the first column only - because the time stamp is so much larger than the other values. Thus, it *seems* as though there are all zeros. In reality, when you print the matrix `M`, it gets printed with a "global scaling factor" of 1E8.

If you don't print column 1 (e.g. `M(:, 2:7)`) things will seem more reasonable. With the example given you get the acceleration in XYZ, and the roll/pitch/yaw. All looking good.

You are being fooled by Matlab's scaling. Your code is fine. And now we know where your iPod was when you acquired sensor data. Must be nice to have a Mexican grill next door!?

Comment: thanks a ton! I guess i have to get used to some of MATLABs idiosyncracies like scaling, but i am sure they come in handy more often than they mess stuff up.

And haha, thanks now i have to remove that data!

Comment: The scaling is actually right there at the top of the printout: `ans = 1.0e+08 *` and then the rest.... I would recommend doing something like `M(:,1) = M(:,1) - M(1,1);` - that will scale the time stamp to t=0 at the first data point. Once all things are of the same magnitude it will be easier to view / manipulate.